# Nested routes won't work using React Router 6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

When I click Add card button (IconButton component) I should be able to navigate to the Add card page but it doesn't work.

This is my code:

App.js:

```
<Routes>
  <Route index element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
  <Route path="signup" element={<Signup />} />
  <Route path="manage-cards" element={<ManageCards />}>
    <Route path="add-card" element={<h1>Hello world</h1>} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="manage-code" element={<ManageCode />} />
</Routes>
```

ManageCards.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import IconButton from "../../components/iconButton/IconButton";

import addCardIcon from "../../assets/img/Add card.png";

const ManageCards = () => {
  return (
    <div className="manage-cards">
      <div className="manage-cards__buttons">
        <Link to="add-card">
          <IconButton
            icon={addCardIcon}
            altText="Add card"
            iconText="Add card"
          />
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ManageCards;
```

Comment: It seems that you forgot to add <Outlet /> in your parent component (ManageCards).

Answer (score 1):

An `<Outlet>` should be used in parent route elements to render their child route elements. This allows nested UI to show up when child routes are rendered. If the parent route matched exactly, it will render a child index route or nothing if there is no index route.

Did you add `Outlet` ?

Comment: `<Outlet />` will add the component in manage-cards page, I want it to be rendered in it's own page not inside the manage-cards page.

Comment: @MohammedModather why are you using a nested router? if the component is parent, don't add it as child.

Comment: Because I want the path to be nested like this: `/manage-cards/add-card/`. By the way, I found a solution for this, you can check my own answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use it

```
import React from "react";
import { Link,Outlet  } from "react-router-dom";

import IconButton from "../../components/iconButton/IconButton";

import addCardIcon from "../../assets/img/Add card.png";

const ManageCards = () => {
  return (
    <div className="manage-cards">
      <div className="manage-cards__buttons">
        <Link to="add-card">
          <IconButton
            icon={addCardIcon}
            altText="Add card"
            iconText="Add card"
          />
        </Link>
      </div>

     <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ManageCards;
```

Comment: This will cause it to render on ManageCards component, I only want it to be rendered on a different page.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to render the add-card in a different page, the problem with Outlet will cause it to render in the same page. So that's how I managed to fix the issue:

```js
<Routes>
  <Route index element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
  <Route path="signup" element={<Signup />} />
  <Route path="manage-cards">
    <Route index element={<ManageCards />} />
    <Route path="add-card" element={<h1>Hello world</h1>} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="manage-code" element={<ManageCode />} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: FYI, when you don't provide an `element` prop to the `Route` it renders an `Outlet` by default.

Comment: Man, thank you for this. Was looking for the same thing.